# How to graph a tree with graphviz?

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, graphviz, decision-tree

I can't reproduce a simple example. Here is how it goes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn as skl
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split as tts



#   import data and give a little overview
sample = pd.read_stata('sample_data.dta')
s = sample

#   Let's learn
X = np.array((s.crisis, s.cash, s.industry, s.current_debt, s.activity)).reshape(1000, 5)
y = np.array(s.wc_measure)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = tts(X, y, test_size = .8)

my_tree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = my_tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = my_tree.predict(X_test)

#   Graph the tree
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
import pydotplus 
dotfile = StringIO() 
tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dotfile) 
pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dotfile.getvalue()).write_png("my_tree.png")
```

When I try to graph the tree, I get the following error:

```
pydotplus.graphviz.InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found
```

Any idea what the problem is? I neatly follow graphviz's documentation.

Comment: Your problem is just with `tree` or with any graphviz graph?

Comment: It runs until tree.export :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seem you didn't install the graphviz software at all. You should [download](http://www.graphviz.org/Download..php) and install it before using the module.

Comment: I used `pip install graphviz`... so that should do, shouldn't it?

Comment: No, it's not enough. `pip install graphviz` installs just the python module that use the graphviz software. Look [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz) at the installation section.

Answer (score 2):

step 1, install C-version of graphviz using '`sudo apt-get install graphviz`' if ubuntu, '`brew install graphviz`' if OSX

step 2, install package 'graphviz' by pip `sudo pip install graphviz`