# Decision Tree Visualization

Tags: python-2.7, graphviz

I am trying to build a decision tree in python and visualize it. However graphviz is creating a problem.

Here is the code that i tried :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import sklearn
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import sklearn.metrics
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn import tree
from io import BytesIO as StringIO
from IPython.display import Image
import pydot
import pydotplus
import graphviz

path = "C:\\Users\\admin\\PycharmProjects\\conference\\New\\decision_tree\\"

data = pd.read_csv(path + "weights.csv")
data_clean = data.dropna()

#data_clean.dtypes()
#data_clean.describe()

predictors = data_clean[['anxiety', 'taking']]
target = data_clean['influence_score']

pred_train, pred_test, tar_train, tar_test = train_test_split(predictors,target, test_size=.2)

#pred_train.shape
#pred_test.shape
#tar_test.shape
#tar_train.shape

classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier()
classifier = classifier.fit(pred_train,tar_train)

predictons = classifier.predict(pred_test)

sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(tar_test,predictons)

data = StringIO()

#out_dot = path + "tree.dot"
tree.export_graphviz(classifier, out_file = data)

graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(data.getvalue())

out_tree = path + "tree_full.pdf"

graph.write_pdf(out_tree)
```

However i keep getting this error.

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py", line 1960, in create
    'GraphViz\'s executables not found')
pydotplus.graphviz.InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found
```

I have followed all the procedure for installing `Graphviz` and `pydotplus` including changing the environment variables and also importing them in python IDE (I am using pycharm). Graphviz version installed 2.38.

How do i make this work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to graph a tree with graphviz?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146728/how-to-graph-a-tree-with-graphviz)

Comment: in that question the poster had not installed graphviz separately, which was causing the problem. I have installed it separately, but still i am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It seems i was making a mistake in updating the environment variables. works fine.